# make calculation and toast it---error

Tags: android, toast

in my app i have three editText where the user can place a number.then.when the user press a button,i get the result of my calculation into another editext.

this is my code,but the app forces down..any help please?

code:

```
 float result = (float) ((((new Double(input11.getText().toString())
                                                    + new Double(input21.getText().toString()))/2)*0.3)+ (new Double(input31.getText().toString())*0.7));

                                    vprosvasis.setText(Float.toString(result));}
```

calculation:

```
 float genikosvathmos = (float) ((new Double(vprosvasis.getText().toString())+new Double(vprosvasis7.getText().toString())+ new Double(vprosvasis2.getText().toString())+new Double(vprosvasis3.getText().toString())
                                                        +new Double(vprosvasis4.getText().toString())+new Double(vprosvasis5.getText().toString())+new Double(vprosvasis6.getText().toString()))/7);


                                 float moria=(float) (((new Float ((genikosvathmos*8)+("vprosvasis * 1.3")+("vprosvasis2 * 0,7"))*100)));       

                                 Toast.makeText(thetiki.this, "Genikos vathmos"+moria , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

logCat:

```
02-23 13:57:50.255: WARN/dalvikvm(20923): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFltImpl(Native Method)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:321)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:291)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at java.lang.Float.<init>(Float.java:111)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at kostas.menu.moria.thetiki$8.onClick(thetiki.java:372)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2461)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8888)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
02-23 13:57:50.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20923):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 13:57:50.399: WARN/ActivityManager(2944):   Force finishing activity kostas.menu.moria/.thetiki
```

Comment: Its not a problem with Toast, there's something wrong with ur number conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a `NumberFormatException`. This is because your float contains Strings and can't be parsed, here: `new Float ((genikosvathmos*8)+("vprosvasis * 1.3")+("vprosvasis2 * 0,7"))*100))`

Simply get rid of the ""

*Edit:*

Furthermore, as `vprosvasis` etc, are EditTexts or some other kind of input you must convert their values in a proper way to to be able to do calculations with them.
One possibility is:

```
float vprosvasisFloat = Float.parseFloat(vprosvasis.getText().toString());
```

Then you can perform your calculations using `vprosvasisFloat` instead of `vprosvasis`

Comment: thanks for your answer..i have tried it but eclipse highlights it and says : The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) EditText, double

Comment: i tried it but :  Cannot invoke getText() on the primitive type float

Comment: Sorry, mixed up genikosvathmos and vprosvasis. It's edited now

Comment: The method parseFloat(String) in the type Float is not applicable for the arguments (Editable)

Comment: What about vprosvasis.getText().toString(); ?

Comment: i want to get into my toast the variable "moria".can the vprosvasis be the problem??(i m just trying your new answer)

Comment: the app still forces down with the NumberFormatException

Comment: My previous comment was an answer to your previous comment. You should write float vprosvasisFloat = Float.parseFloat(vprosvasis.getText().toString()); to avoid the error. Because your program breaks during the calculation of moria.. it breaks before even comming to the line with the Toast. Did you also do this for vprosvasis2?

Answer (score 2):

This line is really strange, you used quotes where you shouldn't, and you used "," as a decimal delimiter. There's also some useless brackets :

```
float moria = (float) (((new Float ((genikosvathmos*8)+("vprosvasis * 1.3")+("vprosvasis2 * 0,7"))*100)));
```

You should write

```
float moria = (float) ((genikosvathmos * 8.0 + vprosvasis * 1.3 + vprosvasis2 * 0.7) * 100.0);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer..i have tried it but eclipse highlights it and says : The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) EditText, double

Comment: All your variables must be numbers (int, double, float, ...). Here at least one of your variables is an EditText. It doesn't make any sense to multiply an EditText with a number

Comment: OR, if its an `EditText` then use `vprosvasis.getText().toString().trim()` and parse it into a suitable DataType before doing `* 3`

Comment: vprosvasis,vprosvasis2...etc are firstly printed into an editText,so i have set them as editext.But,in the end of my app,i would like to get these variables,make my calculation and print it in a toast(when i press a "send" button...

Answer (score 0):

convert moria  to string and then do the Tost..

```
String.valueOf(moria)
```